# Box OAuth2 Authorization on Android

Tags: box-api

Firstly any news on the V2 SDKs for iOS and Android?

The normal flow is:

1. In app: click authorize button.
2. browser opens box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?....
3. User inputs their details.
4. User is taken to an allow/deny page.
5. User taps allow or deny.
6. User is taken back to app via the redirect_uri scheme.

My problem is once the user has put their details (3) in once and arrived at the allow/deny page, any future attempts to authorize full on skip the allow/deny page and go straight to the box home page without ever calling the redirect_uri along with the auth codes.

This can be 'fixed' if the user clears their browsing history/cookies before trying again, which is a long way from ideal. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you setting as your redirect_uri?

Comment: customscheme://auth_token_received

Comment: Also this is on Android Chrome (Default on the nexus 7 at least), I am unsure about stock android browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a potential short term fix until the v2 sdk is released, a web view can be used which will give you full control over things like the cache (we are using one in the sdk).

Comment: I did go this way in the end, it actually seems to be a better user experience as well rather than switching between applications too.